# How to automatically click a href?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I got videos list using AJAX, and me want to play a top video an a light box? So after viewing list how it is possible to play video automatically?

Comment: Nnot a good idea! Let the users play it when they want to play

Comment: yes, but it is my clients requirement. so... me trying

Comment: And you realise that, about two weeks after implementing this, their *next* requirement will be 'an optional way to turn this off?' =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html code

```
<a id="a_lnk" href="http:\\www.cnn.com">cnn</a>​
```

javascript code

```
// find a <a> element with id a_lnk
var lnk = document.getElementById('a_lnk');
lnk.onclick = function(e){
  // do the magic here..
  // e.target is the object that got the click
    window.location = e.target.getAttribute('href');
  return false;
}​
```

complete example here

http://jsfiddle.net/eAFWY/26/

can also be done with jQuery if that is your thing

http://api.jquery.com/click/